# Javascript Undefined Array

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a chrome extension which saves a list of URLs using the chrome.storage API. I'm storing this list in an array with the key "tabs". Basically, the `refreshList()` function calls when the 'browser action' is called. This calls the `getList()` function to get the array of URLs. The `console.log()` calls from `getList()` show that it is working fine (they print out the array object and "is array"), but in `refreshList()` the `console.log` prints our "undefined" and an error occurs saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

```
function refreshList()
{
    var items = getList();
    console.log(items);
    var list = document.getElementById('pin-list');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        var entry = document.createElement("li");
        entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(items[i]));
        list.appendChild(entry);
    }
}

function getList()
{
    var itemsOut;
    chrome.storage.local.get("tabs",function (items){
        itemsOut=items.tabs;
        console.log(itemsOut);
        if (itemsOut instanceof Array)
        {
            console.log("is array");
            return itemsOut;
        }
        else if (typeof(itemsOut)=="undefined")
        {
            console.log("is undefined");
            return [];
        }
        console.log("is something else");
        chrome.storage.local.set({"tabs":[itemsOut]},function(){});
        return [itemsOut];
    });    
}
```

The `refreshList()` function should print out an unordered list of the items in chrome.storage onto the browser action popup.

I'm thoroughly confused. I think it has something to do with passing by reference (or, if I understand it correctly, passing by value where the value is a reference) but I'm not sure how to fix it.
I hope this was clear enough to understand... Thank you in advance :)

Comment: `getList()` returns nothing.

Comment: oh... nevermind... i feel rather stupid now...

Comment: Also, you may want to take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: I changed it so that `itemsOut` was set to whatever would have been returned, and returned itemsOut but the same thing still happened. Does that have something to do with the asynchronous stuff?

Comment: Yes, if your code is async it would return before it has time to finish, thus `undefined`. Follow the link above, it has an in-depth analysis of the problem.